# Detachable menus in gvim are not clickable

Tags: gvim

You can detach the menus in gvim with the scissors symbol. This works, but I cannot click any of the items then.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in gtk2 ([gnome bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627511), [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/619432)).

Unfortunately, as you can see in the gnome bug report, gnome developers are no longer supporting gtk2, and the tear-off menu is a deprecated feature in gtk3. This means the bug is unlikely to be resolved upstream.

The author of vim [is aware of the issue](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vimdev/message/57796), so I'd expect it to be resolved in a future version of vim.